# Macro is not Cooperating with Quotations in Excel VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, macros, vba

I Have a macro containing a line that will change the formula of a cell using R1C1 formula type.

The formula is:

```
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(R[0]C[-2]=0,"",(R[0]C[-20]-R[0]C[-16]))"
```

When ever I attempt to run the macro it always comes up with a dialog box saying

```
    Run-time error '1004':
    Application-defined or object-defined error.
```

And when you click debug it highlights those 2 lines in the macro. And I can't figure out how to fix it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your are missing a close bracket

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(R[0]C[-2]=0,"""",(R[0]C[-20]-R[0]C[-16]))"
```

Edit: corrected to put "" in to formula

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be the quotes, have you tried changing or escaping the quotation marks?

Answer (score 0):

Try use it:

```
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(R[0]C[-2]=0," & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ",(R[0]C[-20]-R[0]C[-16]))"
```

Remember this formula cannot be placed before column 20 or an error will be raised.